# How to add linebreaks in a dynamic tooltip

Tags: html, angular

*All the question I found on SO explain how to add a line break in a tooltip with a known text, defined by programmer.*

In my case, my `title` attribute is dynamic while user is typing in a `textarea` inside a `[(ngModel)] form`.

`[title]="a dynamic [(ngModel)] value"`

If the user types a long text in the `textarea`, tooltip can become really long. I would like to know if there's a way to define a `max-width` for the tooltip in that case to force line-breaks ?

Answer (score 0):

add `&#013;` where ever you need the line breaks.

Comment: Not answering my question.